# Create List View with dynamic image and text in Android

Tags: android, listview

I want to create List View with dynamic image getting from URL and text also get from URL What is the easiest way to implement this List View using Android

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to load dynamic image from URL, it will take times for the phone to load all of images and text into ListView. Until all of images are loaded, users would see a pitch black on the screen. So you may consider using lazy loading technique on your listview (multi-threading) on your app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
I am still trying to customize lazylist.